# Adding values to point by its location in vector layer using QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I have two layers. One is the location of houses, the other is the boundaries of areas in my home town.

[image]

I'd like to add the name of those areas to the points, so I can select them, group them and display them by the area they are located in. Like "*240 of those points are in the area of xyz*"

I did try and select them by the intersect tool but had no success with that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Join Attributes by Location` and choose the point shapefile as input file and Boundary shapefile as join vector layer. Make Sure that both shapefiles have the same projection. You can find the tool from `Vector -> Data Management Tools -> Join Attributes by Location`

[image]