# Joining data associated with geographic coordinate to region in shapefile containing those coordinates?

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins

I have two shapefiles that I essentially need to join, but inconvenience in the boundaries in each shapefile, traditional join methods have proven to be quite difficult (often there are multiple matches). However, one shapefile contains two columns containing the centroid of the area in lat/long, and frankly, simply matching those coordinates to the region in the other file that includes those coordinates would work really well for me. Alternatively, if I could tell QGIS to return the area for which there is the most overlap with the target vector in case it overlaps with more than 1, that would work.

How can I do either of those things?

Comment: sounds like you should be using DB Manager in QGIS to write a SQL spatial query using ST_Intersects on the JOIN of the two tables on ST_Intersects(points.geometry, polygons.geometry)

Comment: I'll give it a shot

Comment: does https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/250489/adding-values-to-point-by-its-location-in-vector-layer-using-qgis help?

Comment: Not quite... the first layer in my shapefile is not comprised of points, and they are not shown as points when overlayed on the map. Rather, the coordinates are listed in the attribute table. In essence, I don't have a "point shapefile," I have an area shapefile with the coordinates of the center of each area listed in the attribute table but not marked on the map itself. DSSPatial's solution looks promising, I'm not too experienced with the software and I am about to try to figure out what it means.

Comment: use the 'add delimited text layer' to convert your table of coordinates to a point layer, you can then use the method above...